# Telegram desktop locking by shortcut?

Tags: security, telegram, shortcut, passcode

How to lock desktop telegram using shortcuts on Ubuntu? (So that I need to enter local passcode to use it further)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some research and the answer is:

> Ctrl + L

[This site](https://winaero.com/blog/telegram-desktop-keyboard-shortcuts/) helped me, there are some extra shortcuts for telegram